# background processes with cloud-init

Tags: linux, shell, virtual-machine, kvm, cloud-init

I'm trying to create a VM which listen to a TCP port via `nc`. I want to start listening at every boot, thus I wrote the following cloud-config file:

```
#cloud-config

# Allows to run runcmd at every boot
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

runcmd:
  # Listen to port 80
  - [ nohup, nc, -k, -l, 80, & ]
```

The process is allegedly killed when cloud-init finishes, despite being detached.

Any ideas? am I really forced to use to `systemd` instead?

Thank you

Comment: Are there any errors reported in `/var/log/cloud-init.log`?

Comment: A couple of notes:
1. 80 in yaml is a number, not the expected type in runcmd, see [here for type details](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#runcmd)

2. cloud_final_modules is from cloud.cfg, but you have #cloud-config - is this expected to be a user-data config (if so, cloud_final_modules is not a valid key)

Comment: @BrettHolman regarding 2), I've been using a similar cloud-init script for starting a systemd service, and it works with no issues

Comment: @BrettHolman Hi, I was wrong, runcmd is not running at every boot as I thought. Can you please help me with that? (Should I open another question?). I pass this cloud config to my OpenStack deployment

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in setting up a systemd service on first boot, I recently [wrote a user-data cloud-init config[1] that does just this](https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/blob/4179fc16e00ebd802a93a0798ce85295cb6a686e/tests/integration_tests/modules/test_ansible.py#L21) that you could use as an example.

[1] Just write the service file with `write_files` then enable && start the service in `runcmd` and it will run on boot every time (cloud-init only needs to run the first time in this scenario).